# SSL config on Ubuntu 22.04 and Apache2

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to configure my Apache2 on Ubuntu 22.04 to use SSL certificates with Nextcloud and Port 443.

Mostly, I try to follow this guide: https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/ubuntu-server-with-apache2-openssl.htm#ssl_certificate_install
from part 2 on because I obtained the certificates from my domain provider.

I have got

- SSL_Certificate.cer
- private key.key
- SSL_certficate_Intermediate.cer

Transferred them onto the server to /etc/ssl/

Created 2 files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/, one for port 80, one for port 443.

The one for port 80 works but when I enable the one for port 443 and https into the site, I get the following error: SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

"systemctl status apache2" says it is active and running.

The site conf for port 443 contains the following:

```
<VirtualHost example.net:443>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nextcloud"
    ServerName example.net

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.net_ssl_certificate.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.net_private_key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.net_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer

    <Directory "/var/www/html/nextcloud/">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud_access.log
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/nextcloud_error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?